# How to run different date ranges for different months in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, where-clause, between

I have a requirement to automate dates for a report. The user runs the report four times a year.

Q1-jan-march- run may1

Q2-Apr-Jun - run Aug1

Q3-July-Sep - run Oct1

Q4-oct-dec - run feb1

when the user runs the query in May he should get the result for SELECT * FROM Table where DATE Between jan1 and march31. How do I write different date ranges according to the month it is being run.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: oracle, sql-server, mysql, ...? Date functions are highly vendor-specific.

Comment: I am using MS SQL SERVER

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to filter on the previous quarter. Here is one way to do it:

```
select *
from mytable
where date >= dateadd(qq, datediff(qq, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)
  and date <  dateadd(qq, datediff(qq, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

This dynamically computes the beginning and end of the previous quarter based on the current date.

Answer (score 0):

If the query subtracts 2 months from the current month, then the functions to determine the beginning and end of the quarter will always return the correct date range.  Something like this

```
with example_run_dates as (
    select cast(v.dt as date) dt
    from (values ('20200501'), ('20200531'), ('20200801'), ('20200831'), 
                 ('20201001'), ('20201031'), ('20210201'), ('20210228')) v(dt))
select cast(dateadd(qq, datediff(qq, 0, mos.two_ago), 0) as date) start_dt,
       cast(dateadd(qq, datediff(qq, 0, mos.two_ago)+1, -1) as date) end_dt
from example_run_dates erd
     cross apply (select dateadd(month, -2, erd.dt) two_ago) mos;
```

Output

```
start_dt    end_dt
2020-01-01  2020-03-31
2020-01-01  2020-03-31
2020-04-01  2020-06-30
2020-04-01  2020-06-30
2020-07-01  2020-09-30
2020-07-01  2020-09-30
2020-10-01  2020-12-31
2020-10-01  2020-12-31
```

Answer (score -2):

DECLARE @FromDate NVARCHAR(255), @ToDate NVARCHAR(255)

SET @FromDate = CASE
WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 5 THEN '20200101'

WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 8 THEN '20200401'

WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 10 THEN CONCAT(YEAR(GETDATE()),'0701')

WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 2 THEN '20201001'
END

SET @ToDate = CASE
WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 5 THEN '20200330'

WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 8 THEN '20200630'

WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 10 THEN CONCAT(YEAR(GETDATE()),'0930')

WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 2 THEN '20201230' END

select @FromDate, @ToDate

Comment: Nope - we should not be using string variables to store dates. Nor should we assume that this code will only and always apply to the current year of 2020. It certainly does not help that your logic is inconsistent and will "work" when the current date falls in November. And relying on implicit datatype conversion is just another problem waiting to be discovered.

Comment: Your logic will ignore the last day of March in Q1 and last day of December in Q4.